# How can I make apt-get wait for another instance to finish?

Tags: command-line, apt, automation

Is there any way I can make `apt-get` wait for the other `apt-get` (or another package manager) process to finish?

I know that, generally, `apt-get` can only run one instance at a time and if we try to run another `apt-get` instance at the same time, then we get a message saying that some other process is using it.

My question is: how can I make `apt-get` wait for the other processes to finish and then run?

An advantage is that there is no need to type the command `apt-get` again, it will be automated after the 1st `apt-get` finishes.